# add custom header to HttpRequestHeaders

Tags: c#, asp.net, http-headers

I am trying to add a custom header to the following object :

```
var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(method, url);
requestMessage.Headers.Add(key, value);
```

If key is equal to an existing header like Host or Connection, everything is working well.
But if I try to add a custom header like MyCustomHeader, it throws an exception. I need to send a request to the destination with this custom header as it's expected by the destination server.
I looked at the documentation of the httpheaders object (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.headers.httpheaders?view=netframework-4.8) and specially at the add method (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.headers.httpheaders.add?view=netframework-4.8#System_Net_Http_Headers_HttpHeaders_Add_System_String_System_String_), and nothing seems to be available for adding custom headers.

Comment: Does the server accept that header that you are trying to send?

Comment: What is the full exception that you encounter?

Comment: @JakeSteffen, yes, the request is just not send as the adding of the custom header throws an exception.

Comment: Try 'X-My-Custom-Header'

Comment: Add a try/catch and add a breakpoint in the catch?  What are the values of key/value that your using?

Comment: @AlexK., when trying to add the header "Content-Length", I get the following exception : InvalidOperationException
Misused header name. Make sure request headers are used with HttpRequestMessage, response headers with HttpResponseMessage, and content headers with HttpContent objects.

Comment: Your code runs fine for me. At which moment is the exception thrown? When you are adding the header, or when you and sending the request? Can you please post the full exception in your question?

Comment: For content headers use the Content object: `requestMessage.Content.Headers.ContentLength = ...`

Answer (score 0):

It is done thru HttpClient class:

try the following:

var client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders <== from here you'll be able to add your custom headers